# Load data on scroll down for bootstrap Model (Lazy Load)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap modal that have scrolling. I want to load data from AJAX call when scroll hit modal bottom (Not Page Bottom). I am using this jQuery code but its not working for this bootstrap modal.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
       // ajax call get data from server and append to the div
 }
});
```

Here is my model

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> 
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height:85%;  margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom:50px;"> 
    <div class="modal-content"> 
        <div class="modal-header"> 
            <h3 class="modal-title">ASDFASDFASDFASDF</h3> 
        </div> 
        <div class="modal-body">ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
      ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
      ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
      ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
      ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
      ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
      ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
      ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
      ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
      ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
      ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF
      ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF ASFASDFASDFASDF</div> 
        <div class="modal-footer">ASDFASDFASDFASDF</div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

And my CSS is

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.modal{
 display: block !important;
}
.modal-dialog{
  overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body{
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/T0yF2ZNTUd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to identify whether `modal-body` has reached bottom as you are scrolling `modal-body` so change `window` to `modal-body` as below:

```
$('.modal-body').scroll(function() {
  if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
       alert('reached bottom');
  }
});
```

**[Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/KUBO1LBkAF)**