# Load contents via ajax when scroll down on bootstrap modal popup

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I want to load contents via ajax when scroll down on bootstrap modal popup. Following code is working fine without popup.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){

    // Do other stuff
    console.log("Scroll down working properly!");
});
```

But I want it to be on bootstrap modal popup. But it is not working for me. My code is:

```
$('.modal-body').scroll(function(){
    console.log("Scroll down working properly!");
});
```

If someone has any experiece with same problom the please share. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like `.modal-body` is not the element what has the scrollbars on it. Would check that first ...

Comment: Thanks @eisbehr. I refered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198913/load-data-on-scroll-down-for-bootstrap-model link. modal-body is class of container where all contents are loaded.

Comment: Finally I got the solutions. Actually all what we are doing is fine but the issue is with event bindings. So When  popup load then we need to bind scroll event like 
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
 $('.modal-body').scroll(function(){
     console.log("Scroll down working properly!");
 });
})

and we also need to bind in success response. That solved my problom. Hope this help to someone.